# Clear User password using Sentry in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I'm trying to clear a user's password, so the old password becomes useless and the User must choose a new one, but if I try to set a `null` or empty password I obtain:

```
Cartalyst \ Sentry \ Users \ PasswordRequiredException
A password is required for user [mickeymouse], none given.
```

This is my code, any idea? Thanks

```
// clearing the user's password
$user->password = null;
$user->save ();

$code = $user->getPasswordResetCode ();
// ...send code by email
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to alter the database and allow it to be nullable() - but I dont think that is a good idea. Pretty much every single password related function is going to assume there is something in the database to compare to.

So rather than try for something complicated - just changed their password to something random - and you have achieved the same outcome:

```
$user->password = str_random(60);
$user->save ();
```

Now their password is useless :)